# Excel Web Query not seeing the table on a page

Tags: javascript, html, css, excel

i have written a web page , with divs, tables CSS etc , and one of the outputs to the page is indended that the results from a query are displayed in a table on the page , and then pulled by an excel web query to the users desktop.

i fully understand the web query system , what i dont understand is why when trying to pass the query string , the page comes up , but NONE of the tables on my page are being selectable for the excel web query.

i am certain its something in my CSS thats stopping it , but i cant find out what tags etc could cause this , any advice is greatly welcome.

Peter

examples here
http://sdrv.ms/NTSH6E

Comment: To help we are going to need to see some code ...

Comment: added link to description for files

Comment: @Peter Maslin You have added a link, but I can't find any HTML or JS files there. Set up a working example to get help…
BTW: Why are your pulling table data from a website using Excel? You also could go the other way around and output a CSV file on the website.

Comment: its an aspx page as i have written the page in .net , i created a dummy aspx page with just raw html in it so simulate the problem. @feeela i have to allow the excel bit as thats what the current customers use , to change the process isnt an option at this stage.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765850/why-is-web-query-not-highlighting-my-table-in-microsoft-excel-2010